# Suggestions for iPhone 7 with Audio IC fault

Tags: iphone, ios, audio, microphone

TLDR; what can I do with an iPhone7 when the microphone doesn't work?

Hello! I've got an iPhone 7 with the dreaded "audio ic fault". The mic doesn't work so the following apps fail:

1. cannot record voice memo, record button does not respond
2. cannot initiate/answer a phone/Facetime/etc call; disconnects immediately upon answer
3. cannot record video with sound; no audio with recording
4. cannot stream audio over airplay
5. [more to come...]

**However** #1, #2 do work when using the BT mic. #3 video does not respond to the BT mic.

The phone is 4+ years old, and apparently the micro-solder IC repair costs more than the phone is worth. So I'm looking for creative suggestions on how I can repurpose this phone. ideas?

- games w/o mic
- [BT webcam with my MacMini](https://www.macworld.co.uk/how-to/iphone-mac-webcam-3793322/)

Comment: You can plug a microphone into the lightning connector for some audio uses.

Comment: Second camera for a zoom call. No annoying feedback.